# sql case statement contained in where clause - conditional logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to match some gender specific data in a SQL query and am having some difficulty in getting the where clause logic correct. I am attempting to use a case statement, but am getting stuck... maybe the case statement isn't the best way to do this, and if so, any viable alternatives would be appreciated.

First, I have a local variable @gender. It will either be 'male', 'female', or null.

The table I am pulling the data from has a column called gender, with one of three values, but will never be null: 'male', 'female', or 'either'.

The logic is simple. If the local variable is 'male', then I want to retrieve any record that has a gender value of 'male' or 'either'.

If the local variable is 'female', then I want to retrieve any record that has a gender value of 'female' or 'either'.

If the local variable is null, then I want to retrieve the record no matter what the gender value is, so all three, 'male', 'female' or 'either.

Here is what I've attempted so far, and I'm not sure how to proceed:

```
 select x from y
    where UPPER(d.Gender) =
        case when upper(@gender) = 'MALE' then 'MALE' 
        when upper(@gender) = 'FEMALE' then 'FEMALE'
        when @gender is null then 'EITHER'
     end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select x from y
    where (( UPPER(d.Gender) = UPPER(@gender) OR  UPPER(d.Gender) ='EITHER') 
               AND @gender IS NOT NULL ) 
          OR (@gender IS NULL AND 1=1)
```

`1=1` condition in `WHERE clause` always evaluates to true and is a hack to essentially ignore WHERE statement , so here if `@gender` is passed `NULL` then all rows of table containing gender **'Male' , 'Female' or 'Either'** are returned ie all all rows returned irrespective of gender

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are using a case conversion. Is your DB case sensitive?

Try this

```
select x from y
    where UPPER(d.Gender) = upper(@gender) 
    OR UPPER(d.Gender) = UPPER(isnull(@gender,'EITHER'))
```

Comment: if @gender is null then it will only retrieve 'Either' , not 'Male' or 'Female' ...

Answer (score 0):

```
select x from y
 where UPPER(customer_type) in 
       ('EITHER', decode(@gender, null, 'FEMALE', @gender),
        decode(@gender, null, 'MALE',  @gender)
       );
```